# Best practice for setting parameter on MainLayout

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a suite of Blazor Micro-Sites.  They all share the same MainLayout, which is created as a Component in a Component Library.  This is to enforce a consistent look and feel.

Some of the Micro-Sites need to set the Visible parameter of a sub-component in the MainLayout, which is in turn exposed as a parameter on MainLayout.

I've accomplished this with a CascadingParameter, but this seems like the wrong approach.

Is this the only approach? Is this the best approach?  Is there a way to set the parameter directly?
Code below, some code removed for simplicity.

```
            <CascadingValue Value="OptionalThingVisible">
                <AuthorizeRouteView DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </CascadingValue>

@code {
    bool OptionalThingVisible = false; //It's hard-coded and won't change.
}
```

Comment: Given what you are trying to do, you might have the best approach already. You are essentially passing in config values programmatically. Another option would be to inject a service that could be implemented per project that does nothing other than expose the config value, but that would be a roll-your-own approach that would only be doing what you are already doing. The way you have it, if you haven't supplied the value you should hit a compiler error, thus enforcing the pattern you have.

Comment: I would use an application view model and inject it as a singleton service. As your application grows it will allow for more "parameters".

Comment: @BrianParker That seems like a great approach, and feels better too. Something about that one just feels cleaner than a cascading parameter.

Comment: @BrianParker that's a good solution, we do this currently in our webapp. We call it "SessionStateService" where we store loads of things. We backup the session in database when user logsout and restore it on login, it works smoothly.

Comment: For my references, I think this describes the right way to do it.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

Cascade a reference to the MainLayout to interested parties like this:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    //....
</CascadingValue>
```

Define a boolean property to get the value:

```
@code
{
    private bool _value;
    public bool Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
           if( _value != value)
           {

            _value == value
            InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
        }
    }
 }
```

Your MainLayout should now look something like this:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    //....
    <SubComponent Value ="Value" />
</CascadingValue>
```

And this is how you pass the boolean value from interested parties:

```
// Gets a reference to the MainLayout component
[CascadingParameter]
public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Layout.Value= false;

}
```

Note that you can get the same functionality using services...but, I'm of the opinion, that this is preferable in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen the cascading parameter of "this" used elsewhere and always wondered how that behaved. Now it seems more clear.  I like this approach as it uses the full MainLayout as the container for optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's a perfectly valid approach, which I have used.  However can I make a couple of suggestions on the implementation.

With you're implementation you can only have one boolean as a cascaded value - you haven't given it a name property.  So if you with to continue with a bool I suggest you qualify the cascade with a name - [see MS Docs for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

You should consider cascading an object, say `LayoutOptions`, where `optionalthing` is just a property.  This gives you more scope if you decide you have more than one `optionalthing` and you don't need to qualify it because it's unique anyway.

Comment: @enet and I have both answered and his approach is just as valid.

Comment: Thank you. I'm choosing the other one as the answer as it seems more flexible as well as has code samples which makes it a little more clear to read and understand. Thank you for your feedback.